# date in MySQL using PHP and it doesn't seem to be working

Tags: php, mysql, date

I searched the site already to see if this question has been addressed already and found no results, but if it has then I appologize and if you can link me to that thread I'll refer to that to solve my problem.

I am trying to save a date in MySQL using PHP and it doesn't seem to be working. The field in MySQL is the "date" type and when I read data from that field it shows as 0000-00-00, so I have tried saving the data as 2009-09-24 for example, but it doesn't seem to work. I have tried saving it with quotations to make it a string, and without quotations and I still can't seem to figure it out.

Does anyone know how I can format the date propely so I can save it in MySQL?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following where $t is a timestamp (`time()`) or nothing

```
function MysqlDate($t=0)
{
    if ($t==0)
        return date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    else
        return date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $t);
}

var_dump(MysqlDate());
```